# Electronic items limit to India

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, electronic-items

If I take one brand new laptop and a brand new ipad to India, will I be subject to any duties?

Answer (score 1):

I have traveled with two laptops before several times.
I carry one laptop in my carry-on luggage and another in my checked bags.
It was fine. Nobody asked me anything through immigration check or security check.
It is very common these days for one person to carry couple of gadgets with them while travelling due to work or other reasons.
If asked in the declaration form to declare electronics, than declare both items.